# Socket Programming: Connecting client in Windows to server in Linux (running on Virtual Machine)

Tags: c#, sockets, networking

I m writing a C# program of a client which using TCP socket to connect to an [engine named "Julius"](http://julius.sourceforge.jp/) - [English Version](http://julius.sourceforge.jp/en_index.php?q=index-en.html)  - running on CentOS. If I use a real computer running CentOS, my program connected to Julius sucessfully. But my program does not work if I use CentOS on VM Player. Can you tell me what is the reason?
Here's my code:

---

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
public class SocketClient
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        int portNum = 10500; //Julius is now working as a server and waiting for connecting from client at port 10500
        String IpAddr = "192.168.2.106"; //the ip address of my virtual CentOS
        try
        {
            TcpClient client;
            NetworkStream ns; 
            client = new TcpClient(IpAddr, portNum);
            ns = client.GetStream();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex);
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you ping your VM by its IP address?

Comment: Yes I can. Both of pinging from Windows to Virtual machine and the reverse direction are ok.

Comment: Can you, from a CMD window, do telnet 192.168.2.106 10500 and/or even from your Linux machine.
Can you connect? If you can't connect then check the firewall setting or disable it for a while and test again.

Comment: Thank you Bob Horn and Ja_mesa. I've re-checked my connection by telnet, also I can ping but cannot telnet. So I disabled firewall on CentOS and my program worked well!